# How to save user's daily progress?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm building an app where I'm trying to store the user's progress on a game.
I want to be able to store the score of a player on a daily basis, and then retrieve the day's score when I look for the date.

I wanted to store a dictionary in the database, with keys being the dates when the user played and the values being the score, but I can't store a dictionary with GAE.

How can I do? 
I'm using google appengine with python

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an easy way would be to create a db.Model to represent an entry in the dictionary you were originally thinking about. Just to sketch it out, what I mean is something similar to this:

```
class DailyProgress(db.Model):
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    score = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Then, you could store a list of those for each of your users.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can be transformed back and forth between a list-of-tuples.

```
aTupleOfTuples= tuple( someDict.items() )

aDict = dict( aTupleOfTuples )
```

This is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I think the user is struggling more with how to represent this in the app engine datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Either unpack the dictionary into a [Datastore.Model](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html) or more quickly, but more opaquely [pickle.dumps()](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) the dictionary into a string and store that via Gql.

Comment: It's not a Gql.Model. It's a Datastore model. GQL is just a layer on top of the datastore for people who don't want to learn the Query API.

Comment: Pardon my being loose with my nomenclature, no offense intended; fixed.